# How to connect mongodb with react js?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I had made a contact form in react js and now i wnat that if user fills the form then his data will go to my mongo db collections from my react app. Please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you show what you have tried so far ? Here's a guide to help improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's difficult to help you if there is no code to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you cannot connect straight to MongoDB from a React app, assuming we are talking about client side rendered React, not Next.js or Gatsby.js. You would need to write an api that connects to an instance of MongoDB, and your React app will do calls to that api. Alternatively you can use cloud functions, for example Netlify’s: https://www.netlify.com/products/functions/.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't.

You need a backend to communicate with MongoDB. You can write your backend code in nodeJS, python, Java etc. Or you can try [MongoDB Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/).

Answer (score 0):

## ReactJS

> ReactJS is a front end framework. React does not communicate with the database unless you have built a REST API with the backend.

If you have less idea about **frontend or backend**. Then feel free to google about it.

## Suggestion

Please use firebase as it is frontend friendly and helps you learn database systems.

#### In layman's term

React can't communicate with backend on its own unless a REST API is set up using a backend tech